# Are Friendly URLs secured under HTTPS?

Tags: security, networking, ssl, https

I know that query with parameters are secured under HTTPS, e.g. https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow

But what about the friendly URLs like twitter, https://twitter.com/#!/search/stackoverflow , is this secure and can't be intercepted by anyone?

Regards,

Comment: It can *always* be intercepted by shoulder surfing

Comment: @awoodland: Good point. "Can't be intercepted in transit" would be indeed more precise; other avenues of attack still apply (e.g. trojans on the client or a hacked server).

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question as pertaining to content under a URL rather than URL/parameters itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**; the entire URL is encrypted when transmitted over HTTPS, no matter what its contents are; also, it doesn't matter if the request is normal or AJAX.

(there is nothing like "friendly URLs" or "hostile URLs" or "neutral URLs" anywhere in the HTTP spec, just URLs. The protocol itself is completely oblivious to what processing the server does with the URL - "friendly URLs" is just a convenient way of saying "URLs that are somewhat easy to grasp for **humans**"; this has no bearing on the underlying protocols. For HTTP, the client sends a request for an URL to a server, and the server gives back a response. As long as the URL is in a valid format, its content is immaterial. )

(aside: the part after the `#` (fragment) is client-side and as such not transmitted in requests at all; whatever processing is done on that happens on the client side, possibly with AJAX)

Comment: I see, so supposing that there is a man-in-the-middle then the only thing that he can gain is the domain name for the request. Other that that it is secured.

Comment: @Affar: The IP address, and possibly the domain name (from DNS).

Comment: @Affar: Hmm, it also appears that the domain name can be captured if the client uses SNI, as the domain name is sent unencrypted in that case - but only the domain name. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication